# Sending string in quotes from html to php

Tags: php, html, string, syntax, quotes

I have a html form tag that sends this string to a php file:

value='network="export"'

when loaded in php, it shows up as:

network=\"export\

what would be the proper syntax to use in html so when loaded in php, it'll show up as:

network="export"

hope my question wasnt confusing, thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't show up as `network=\"export\"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to [disable magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If the string looks like this: `network=\"export\"` then you can remove the slashes using: `stripslashes()`

Usage here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled in your php configuration.  That documentation page includes information about what this setting does, and how you can disable it.